# Subscribing to incoming transaction does not work

Tags: transactions, java-sdk

```
    paymentsRequest.stream(new EventListener<OperationResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(OperationResponse payment) {
            System.out.println("TEST TEST TEST");
```

This does not print anything. Never. No incoming, no outgoing TX. Tried to supply both private KeyPair and KeyPair created using public accountId only. And yes I do import correct EventListener:

```
import org.stellar.sdk.requests.EventListener;
import org.stellar.sdk.requests.PaymentsRequestBuilder;
```

Other operations like balance, tx history, search tx by hash, sign & send tx works without any problems. I'm using a week old github sourcecode.

EDIT: and the link is working https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB/payments

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you were running into a bug, but the following basic code does work and shows how you can use streaming with the Java SDK. This was tested with the Stellar Java SDK `0.6.0`, which [you can grab here](https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/releases/tag/0.6.0).

```java
package playground;

import org.stellar.sdk.KeyPair;
import org.stellar.sdk.Server;
import org.stellar.sdk.requests.EventListener;
import org.stellar.sdk.requests.PaymentsRequestBuilder;
import org.stellar.sdk.responses.operations.OperationResponse;

public class App {
    public static void streamPayments() {
        Server server = new Server("https://horizon.stellar.org");
        KeyPair account = KeyPair.fromAccountId(
                "GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB");
        PaymentsRequestBuilder paymentsRequest = server.payments().forAccount(account);
        paymentsRequest.stream(new EventListener<OperationResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(OperationResponse event) {
                String fmt = String.format(
                        "ID: %s Created At: %s\nOperation Type: %s\nSource Account: %s\n" +
                        "TxHash: %s\nSuccess?: %s\n\n", event.getId(), event.getCreatedAt(),
                        event.getType(), event.getSourceAccount().getAccountId(),
                        event.getTransactionHash(), event.isTransactionSuccessful());
                System.out.println(fmt);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        streamPayments();
    }
}
```

In fact, it prints out the following:

```
ID: 89778702115696641 Created At: 2018-11-09T19:21:20Z
Operation Type: create_account
Source Account: GA5XIGA5C7QTPTWXQHY6MCJRMTRZDOSHR6EFIBNDQTCQHG262N4GGKTM
TxHash: e900a099a3c2d3ba5b2a51240b26e71fc5a92d96a7b35fa0b143c26e5e05c6a6
Success?: true


ID: 89957716352622593 Created At: 2018-11-12T08:58:50Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: 9ca53a6dfc57f583d0deef2c60e7b0bb18f844399167b83d439a13c31b5da95a
Success?: true


ID: 90043156137000961 Created At: 2018-11-13T14:22:06Z
Operation Type: create_account
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: 5ff19b1adf7265ea338aabbd515260109645b188dac0c692080a4784dbb69c6d
Success?: true


ID: 90043448194768897 Created At: 2018-11-13T14:27:47Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: e5305eaa6900e633391d0edcf9676344584a9c74768dc55a22f32854928b17b4
Success?: true


ID: 90740701775593473 Created At: 2018-11-23T13:34:39Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: e9f9c409a1f2b22b7161b6aaf45909f51d3ecb6706dc8dbb77dd7f15082a2bd8
Success?: true


ID: 90742140589621249 Created At: 2018-11-23T14:02:50Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: 624fcd3872588007768660e9d8bc19f0bdca55dd3a8605bd25ba8703da5bc53a
Success?: true


ID: 90742278028529665 Created At: 2018-11-23T14:05:31Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: 5a487ab1fd6db4564c4549ec4b63489156d85867b000e99057853317755f5e37
Success?: true


ID: 90742415467511809 Created At: 2018-11-23T14:08:12Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: c70ec25250a6bb7eb4f9037a820f5dd8167c17ffa1afb1059ff5526c787cf59d
Success?: true


ID: 90742454122237953 Created At: 2018-11-23T14:08:57Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: d89ec9437890169da5b4e4e360c619794593df51cd8d029a6d0db977ae291367
Success?: true


ID: 90742711820300289 Created At: 2018-11-23T14:14:01Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: 975df76798e76f714d6c23bf9c768fafdd7c0945fdc2c67e1852b69a70e261b9
Success?: true


ID: 90742724705202177 Created At: 2018-11-23T14:14:16Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: 5f4a5d61c062640bcb1ee4423b297471d89f7bd5c4df171c1676949da803916d
Success?: true


ID: 90742853554184193 Created At: 2018-11-23T14:16:46Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: 2a477ec03c03e995eef17d530fc8ce88dc87e0abd2a2061de41855c32ff072f1
Success?: true


ID: 91011495168610305 Created At: 2018-11-27T10:34:26Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: 7d88467d76e5dd3428ada61a49abe12587c60032056d38947eca2f8fefc0c289
Success?: true


ID: 91011533823283201 Created At: 2018-11-27T10:35:22Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: 94cbd7cd09b69eab900788190f63cd3085247f471c06cb696b5eff7e38b83aeb
Success?: true


ID: 91015936164810753 Created At: 2018-11-27T12:09:32Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: 27b2264a5118c6bde1eaa86eef0b8dc5eff425be6e566f33729d864243fdacc7
Success?: true


ID: 91019247584591873 Created At: 2018-11-27T13:14:20Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: cf7f2016fdddc864ce00b33aaa2f813c9bc21d306c82aa1fe128807d0bfb6519
Success?: true


ID: 91019793045426177 Created At: 2018-11-27T13:25:00Z
Operation Type: payment
Source Account: GBBKXF2HOGIVFLYY5AQOJ4ER2D5JPK4IQDQTSZ6WHKTH6C6HPQWFA2LB
TxHash: 616a916ae96436f8ed1c93aae29aaf025675a4891e8056664de8eaac67cb4076
Success?: true
```